# Determine what GPU is running through WMI

Tags: python, windows, wmi, gpu

I am trying to write a python script for to figure out which GPU (dedicated or integrated) is currently running. I have managed to make it work so far by running dxdiag and parsing the output for the mode of each gpu device, but this is taking way too long. Does anyone know how dxdiag gets this information? Is there a way to get the info through Windows management Instrument? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`DXDiag` most **probably** picks up data from `WMI` tables. *I need to confirm it though.*

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController GET Adapterram
```

will provide you the information that you are looking for. If you want more information just run below mentioned command.

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController
```

And if you want **GPU name**

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController GET Name
```

**Updated**

Adding an example for better understanding.
You can map between below mentioned tables with `deviceid` and get the information.

```
instance of Win32_VideoController
{
    AdapterCompatibility = "Intel Corporation";
    AdapterDACType = "Internal";
    AdapterRAM = 1073741824;
    Availability = 3;
    Caption = "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600";
    ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
    ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
    CreationClassName = "Win32_VideoController";
    CurrentBitsPerPixel = 32;
    CurrentHorizontalResolution = 1920;
    CurrentNumberOfColors = "4294967296";
    CurrentNumberOfColumns = 0;
    CurrentNumberOfRows = 0;
    CurrentRefreshRate = 59;
    CurrentScanMode = 4;
    CurrentVerticalResolution = 1080;
    Description = "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600";
    DeviceID = "VideoController1";
    DitherType = 0;
    DriverDate = "20150911000000.000000-000";
    DriverVersion = "20.19.15.4285";
    InfFilename = "oem79.inf";
    InfSection = "iHSWD_w10";
    InstalledDisplayDrivers = "igdumdim64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd12umd64.dll,igdumdim32,igd10iumd32,igd10iumd32,igd12umd32";
    MaxRefreshRate = 75;
    MinRefreshRate = 50;
    Monochrome = FALSE;
    Name = "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600";
    PNPDeviceID = "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&SUBSYS_18E5103C&REV_06\\3&11583659&0&10";
    Status = "OK";
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    SystemName = "---------";
    VideoArchitecture = 5;
    VideoMemoryType = 2;
    VideoModeDescription = "1920 x 1080 x 4294967296 colors";
    VideoProcessor = "Intel(R) HD Graphics Family";
};




instance of Win32_PnPEntity
{
    Caption = "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600";
    ClassGuid = "{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}";
    CompatibleID = {"PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&REV_06", "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412", "PCI\\VEN_8086&CC_030000", "PCI\\VEN_8086&CC_0300", "PCI\\VEN_8086", "PCI\\CC_030000", "PCI\\CC_0300"};
    ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
    ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
    CreationClassName = "Win32_PnPEntity";
    Description = "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600";
    DeviceID = "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&SUBSYS_18E5103C&REV_06\\3&11583659&0&10";
    HardwareID = {"PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&SUBSYS_18E5103C&REV_06", "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&SUBSYS_18E5103C", "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&CC_030000", "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&CC_0300"};
    Manufacturer = "Intel Corporation";
    Name = "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600";
    PNPClass = "Display";
    PNPDeviceID = "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_0412&SUBSYS_18E5103C&REV_06\\3&11583659&0&10";
    Present = TRUE;
    Service = "igfx";
    Status = "OK";
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    SystemName = "-------";
};
```

Comment: There seems to be no difference between the output of Win32_VideoController when one GPU is running over the other, except the MaxRefreshRate = 0 and there is no MinRefreshRate for the GPU not in use. Is this the only way to tell? I thought there would be some sort Mode value that would tell like there is in DxDiag.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean "GPU is running over the other". I have updated the answer with an example. And you can rely on WMI for all the information. Hope it helps.

Comment: When running dxdiag I am able to see both GPUs (integrated Intel, and dedicated Nvidia) listed as Devices. The GPU that is currently running has its Current Display Mode listed as 1920x1080 32bit 60hz the other GPU is listed as n/a. When running the above WMI commands there is no distinguishing field for which GPU is the current one in use. All the fields are the same when a GPU is running or not running except the MaxRefreshRate.